# Is the lookup attribute on @Resource a replacement for ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I tried to search on the internet but couldn't find a definite answer for this:

Is using

```
@Resource(name="abc", lookup="myJndiName")
private Queue myQueue;
```

in a EJB 3.1 session bean equivalent to

```
@Resource(name="abc")
private Queue myQueue;
```

without the lookup but with the entry in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml:

```
<session name="StatelessBean">
    <resource-env-ref name="abc" binding-name="myJndiName"/>
</session>
```

?

I.e. if I'm using the lookup attribute, then I don't have to specify the resource-env-ref anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the lookup attribute is functionally equivalent to specifying the value in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, but not quite a replacement. If a value is specified in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, it will override the value provided on the 'lookup' attribute. ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml is still useful in that it allows the binding to be changed without recompiling the application.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering, is there a documentation where this is described? That would be maybe a good reference for other things as well.

Comment: The http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cejb_ref.html and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html topics in the knowledge center both have good information about bindings and lookups.